# jQuery Datatables: Request multiple endpoints to aggregate final table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I try to figure out if I can using jQuery Datatables with the following limitations:

Having a bunch of microservices with multiple endpoints each (e.g. /api/resource_a, /api/resource_b, ...).

Is there a way to tun multiple requests and finally "aggregate" the results (using a custom function) before rendering?

I have no idea which parts of datatables needs to take a close eye on to find out if this framework fits my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery DataTables v1.10 consider the [ajax option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax):

> **function ajax( data, callback, settings )**:
>
> As a function, making the Ajax call is left up to yourself allowing complete control of the Ajax request. Indeed, if desired, a method other than Ajax could be used to obtain the required data, such as Web storage or a Firebase database.

For jQuery DataTables v1.9 consider the [fnServerData option](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref)

> **function fnServerData ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings )**:
>
> This parameter allows you to override the default function which obtains the data from the server ($.getJSON) so something more suitable for your application. For example you could use POST data, or pull information from a Gears or AIR database.

In both cases you should be able to provide a custom function that makes multiple requests, joins the data and returns it to the table via the `callback` or `fnCallback`.